# screen/image sharing with pointer

Tags: collaboration, presentation, sharing, screen-sharing, learning

I'm doing language exchange online. We are sharing our screens in Google Meet and show an image/photo. We discuss things in the picture so being able to see the mouse pointer is great. The problem in is that the other party doesn't have a mouse pointer. So to talk about something in return with showing what you are talking about is difficult. It would be of extremely help if both parties could use a pointer at the same screen/image.

Thus I'm looking for a collaboration tool that allows to share the screen or an image. And allows to show both parties pointers. If it's not free it should only cost one fee to add unlimited users. Also there must be a trial period at least. I found collabshot and awwapp but both don't have the trial with the pointers.

Is there such a website/app/software?

Answer (score 0):

I just found one option myself.
Zoom offers to annotate pointers though it didn't work for me. But if you allow remote access both can use the same pointer at least. It's free.
It's not a good option though, given the security issues zoom had continuously.
I should probably mention that remote access itself is pretty dangerous of course.

Comment: It depends on who you are expecting to spy on you :-)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Dead Simple Screen Sharing](https://deadsimplescreensharing.com/)

Feature list from their website

> **Free Screen Sharing and Online Meetings**
> right from your browser
> Dead Simple Screen Sharing is the only completely free screen sharing solution.
>
> - Share Screen for Unlimited Time. No time limits.
> - Multiple users can share their screen simultaneously.
> - Free Video and Audio Chat.
> - Unlimited Participants.
> - Free 5k Screen Sharing
> - No Sign Up and Login
> - Live Chat with File and Image Sharing